# Emulsifying action of bile salts

Tags: bile

n my book, It is given that the action of Bile salts (a part of Bile juice) is similar to the emulsifying action of soaps on dirt. The role of bile salts is to break down the fat into smaller globules.

I don't understand this and cannot find it on the internet. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

[The Wikipedia entry on Bile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bile#Function) says it all:

> Bile acts to some extent as a surfactant, helping to emulsify the lipids in food. Bile salt anions are hydrophilic on one side and hydrophobic on the other side; consequently, they tend to aggregate around droplets of lipids (triglycerides and phospholipids) to form micelles, with the hydrophobic sides towards the fat and hydrophilic sides facing outwards. The hydrophilic sides are negatively charged, and this charge prevents fat droplets coated with bile from re-aggregating into larger fat particles.